# String to array

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, string-parsing

users of site can fill in form input something like that - `array(1,23,4,5)` and so on.
Can be variants like `array(array('qwe'))` and others.

How i can convert all type of strings like specified to regulary arrays

So i need to convert

```
array(
    "String" => "I am a string", 
    "bool" => true, 
    "int" => 99, 
    "float" => 9.45, 
    "array" => array()
);
```

To

```
array(6) {
  ["String"]=>
  string(13) "I am a string"
  ["bool"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["int"]=>
  int(99)
  ["float"]=>
  float(9.45)
  ["array"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

Also i cannot use `eval` couse of security reasons

P.S. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Why would you need this?

Comment: Those are the exact same arrays, one is the output of `print_r` and one `var_dump`.

Comment: @AbraCadaver no, no... He want convert STRING (1) to array (2). So if someone will write from hand `array` structure - he want to do array from this.

Comment: Does it need to be in PHP's array format? Something like JSON would be more succinct (and much more secure, because it removes the possibility of executing arbitrary code)

Comment: I thinking about replace format, but php array format is better for users in my case. So json and others are a backup case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used an PHPSandbox to parse an php and get all variations within an parsing arrays.

I use code from https://github.com/fieryprophet/php-sandbox

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this without eval() would be to write it out to a temp file and include it (just as risky and may be invalid so it generates a parse error):

```
file_put_contents('temp.php', '<?php $array = ' . $_POST['field'] . '; ?>');
include('temp.php');
var_dump($array);
```

Comment: This is a security breach. Couse i can write something like `array(mail(...));`